# WPF Treeview Not Updating After Rearchitecting to MVVM

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I've created an application to load specifically-formated XML files and edit its fields through a WPF GUI.  However, being new to C#, I was not aware of the MVVM pattern upon writing it, and I'd taken the quick and dirty route of simply coding everything in the code-behind.  However, Upon rearchitecting, I cannot seem to get the treeview (that was working before) to update anymore.

Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TableBuilder.Views.XmlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TableBuilder.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TableBuilder.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:XmlViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView x:Name="XmlTree" SelectedItemChanged="XmlView_SelectedItemChanged">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="20" Margin="2" Source="../Images/Red_Bullet.png" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TableBuilder.Helpers;

namespace TableBuilder.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for XmlView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class XmlView : UserControl
    {
        RelayCommand selectedItemChanged { get; set; }
        public XmlView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void XmlView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            //((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SelectedItemChangedCommand = (RelayCommand)sender;
            Console.WriteLine("XmlView selected item changed event triggered");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Xml;
using TableBuilder.Helpers;
using TableBuilder.Models;

namespace TableBuilder.ViewModels
{
    class XmlViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private TreeView _xmlTree;
        public TreeView XmlTree
        {
            get { return _xmlTree; }
            set
            {
                _xmlTree = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("XmlTree");
            }
        }

        public XmlViewModel()
        {
            xmlModel = new XmlModel();

            TreeView XmlTree = new TreeView();
            TreeViewItem node = new TreeViewItem();
            node.Header = "Test";
            XmlTree.Items.Add(node);

            xmlModel.PropertyChanged += XmlModel_CurrentChanged;
        }

        private void XmlModel_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewItem xmlTreeItems = GetTreeViewItems();
            TreeView XmlTree = new TreeView();
            XmlTree.Items.Add(xmlTreeItems);

        }

        private TreeViewItem GetTreeViewItems()
        {
            // Find the filename of the XML document
            Uri uri = new Uri(xmlModel.XmlDoc.BaseURI);
            string filename = "";
            if (uri.IsFile)
            {
                filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            }

            // Populate the TreeView
            TreeViewItem TitleNode = new TreeViewItem()
            {
                Header = filename,
                Tag = "Title Node",
            };
            PopulateTree(TitleNode, xmlModel.XmlDoc.ChildNodes);
            return TitleNode;
        }

        private void PopulateTree(TreeViewItem parent, XmlNodeList nodes)
        {
            TreeViewItem item;
            Dictionary<string, string> dict;
            bool isSmallestChild;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {

                // Ignore all comments in the XML document
                if (!node.Name.Contains("#comment"))
                {
                    // Add to TreeView
                    item = toTreeViewItem(node);

                    isSmallestChild = false;
                    dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (child.Name.Contains("type") ||
                            child.Name.Contains("value") ||
                            child.Name.Contains("units"))
                        {
                            isSmallestChild = true;
                        }
                        if (isSmallestChild)
                        {
                            dict.Add(child.Name, child.InnerText);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isSmallestChild)
                    {
                        PopulateTree(item, node.ChildNodes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.Tag = dict;
                    }
                    parent.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private TreeViewItem toTreeViewItem(XmlNode node)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem()
            {
                Header = node.Name.Contains("#") ? node.InnerText : node.Name,
            };
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the model:

```
using System.Xml;
using TableBuilder.Helpers;

namespace TableBuilder.Models
{
    public class XmlModel : ModelBase
    {
        private XmlDocument _xmlDoc;
        public XmlDocument XmlDoc
        {
            get { return _xmlDoc; }
            set
            {
                _xmlDoc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("XmlDoc");
            }
        }

        public XmlModel()
        {
            XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the viewmodel base class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using TableBuilder.Models;

namespace TableBuilder.Helpers
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        static protected RedModel redModel { get; set; }
        static protected XmlModel xmlModel { get; set; }
        static protected MainModel mainModel { get; set; }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the model base class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TableBuilder.Helpers
{
    public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are a lot of sloppy practices in the code; this is my first C#/WPF application.  To help restrict the scope of this question, I just want to know why I can't set treeview data from my viewmodel.  I've tried poking around Google, but haven't been successful.  I should note that I was able to substitute the treeview with a textbox and set data to the textbox from the viewmodel without issue.

Comment: A TreeView is an ItemsControl. You should bind a collection of items to it, right? Second, in your view model, your XmlTree property is of type TreeView. Don't do that; View models don't create and manipulate UIElements directly (viewmodels are not the view...(: ) I guess, if this is your first WPF app (using databinding and MVVM), don't start with a TreeView but something simpler like a ListBox, or a ComboBox (if you get a listbox working with databinding, then start attacking hierachical TreeViews...)

Comment: (I don't know what specifically you were searching for in Google, but there are plenty of tutorials and blog posts about WPF basics/databinding, MVVM and how to use a TreeView. I am sure you can find them with Google if you just try...)

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're correct about the collection of items.  How would I convert this code to do that?

Comment: I have wasted days trying to get this to work.  Believe me, I've used Google.  I even followed a tutorial when creating this.  I even had this working until I moved this code out of my code-behind.  I even have other views that have list boxes and such in them for this application.  Additionally, I do not have another option than using the TreeView.

Comment: You don't convert this code. Don't take it the wrong way, i don't want to be mean :) But your whole view model there seems to consists of code that directly manipulates UI elements. Viewmodels only interact with the UI through data bindings and commands (ideally). I would suggest you start with a simpler use case with a ListBox. Create a viewmodel with a property that provides a collection of elements. Read some tutorials about WPF listboxes (or ItemControls) how you can bind the listbox against this collection property in your viewmodel...

Comment: I don't believe you found a (WPF) tutorial that taught you to manipulate UI elements directly in a viewmodel instead of using databindings... ;-)

Comment: What type does my XmlTree property need to be?

Comment: Like I said, I created the code in the code-behind, not in the viewmodel.  Please read the whole comment before replying.  It's not constructive.

Comment: XmlType should be a collection of a type you choose/implement for your elements in that tree. Your choice. Anyway, i guess you really need some more quality time with some tutorials ;-)

Comment: And also like I said, I have other views/viewmodels in this very same application that contain working listboxes and such.  I am not having trouble with anything other than the treeview.

Comment: I am sorry, but to be honest (my apologies), seeing your code example above (which is the complete absence of data bindings and the anti-thesis to MVVM), i am not convinced you currently understand MVVM basics nor how to utilize databindings properly :(((

Comment: That's exactly why I am here.  For help understanding what I don't know.

Comment: And as I said in the original post, I am aware of most of these problems.  I am in the process of converting to MVVM.  Please only post constructive comments.  I know that I do not understand MVVM, or even WPF.  That's what I'm here for.

Comment: Wrong place :( Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. You need to spend some time learning the ropes, that is not something that can be provided to you (or anybody) else in a single answer. That's what tutorials are about, and StackOverflow is not a tutorial site...

Comment: "_Please only post constructive comments._" I am sorry if you find the suggestion that you will benefit from spending some time with tutorials not constructive :((( (I mean, the answer to your problems here would be essentially a tutorial about WPF and MVVM, so...)

Comment: Again, I'm aware that I need to keep "learning the ropes".  All I asked was why my treeview doesn't update.  You could provide answers such as "use ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>" or something similar.  I do not care about the rest of the issues in the program.

Comment: "_All I asked was why my treeview doesn't update._" That was already addressed in my 1st comment. ("_You should bind a collection of items to it, right?_") "Items" might perhaps not my best choice of wording there, better is to use the term "elements" (as to not confuse it with "TreeItems")

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> is a good choice. However, ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> not so much. As i also said in my 1st comment, viewmodels don't mess around with UI elements at all. (ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> would require the viewmodel to mess around with TreeViewItem, which is a UI element...)

Comment: Give me a concrete example...

Comment: An example about what?

Comment: What's the type that I need to set my collection to?  Is the best practice to create a custom class to define my type?  If I do this, how will my XAML be affected?

Comment: Yes, (unless you use 3rd-party frameworks providing bindable model classes) usually you create your own data type(s) (i.e., model class) with properties for the information contained by instances of this data type. Your datatemplate used by the ItemsControl (ListBox/TreeView) then binds against those properties to 'present' the respective information. If you need to know more, MVVM/databinding tutorial time ;-)

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get it to display one item.  I modified my XmlModel class to fit the description you gave above.  I see that a simple list doesn't contain the necessary hierarchical properties that a tree would normally have, but I assume I can just create another property in XmlModel that contains another list of its children, so I should be able to make it work.

Comment: Here's a good article that might help you understand how to structure things: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks Robin, that helped quite a bit.  One question though; I've updated my code to the format elgonzo specified, and I can now properly update my treeview.  However, it currently only works within the constructor.  I am currently implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my ViewModelBase, and I'm properly setting my bound property and calling the OnPropertyChanged(nameof(myBoundProperty)) in the mutator.  Do you have any resources that might help debug this?  Most sources say I'm either not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or am not broadcasting an OnPropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the above comment section for the solution.  elgonzo pointed out the major architectural issue that occurred during the rearchitecting process: view models do not directly interact with UI elements, they interact with data that is bound to the UI elements in the XAML.

The other missing piece was due to the fact that I was instantiating my viewmodels again in my mainviewmodel to create the appropriate aesthetic, however, this destroys the datacontext of the child windows, meaning I was only able to manipulate the data within the constructor.  The solution was to instantiate the VIEWS when changing aspects of the UI, not the viewmodels.  Doing this preserves the datacontext.

**Edit:**
My XmlPane was not sending a notification that it was being updated.  Instantiating my views over the viewmodel was a consequence of this, not what I had mentioned above.